# How to make a text from Standard Input be lazy-evaluated?

Tags: java, string, escaping, lazy-evaluation

I have a simple program that gets input from the user and then prints it! (silly, right?)
:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
}
```

Now, imagine I give this to it :

```
abc \n abc
```

It will print the same String. Is there any way to make it evaluate "\n" as a new-line character and print :

```
abc
abc
```

Comment: The escape sequence is a way to put special characters inside Java code. In files you can insert these characters with normal editing commands. However, if you just want to parse the two characters "\n", you can use a regex to do this.

Comment: You could probably use `scan.nextLine().replace("\\n", "\n")`